# What does this expression do? Why is it useful?

Tags: javascript

I was looking through the code of a [library](https://github.com/Adphorus/react-date-range/blob/master/lib/Calendar.js#line-73) and found the following line:

```
var date = (0, _utilsParseInputJs2['default'])(props.date, format);
```

It is unclear to me what `(0, _utilsParseInputJs2['default'])` does. It seems that it is supposed to return a function, but I've never seen anything like it before. Why the `(0,`?

https://github.com/Adphorus/react-date-range/blob/master/lib/Calendar.js#line-73

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator covers the "does". Useful is another question.

Comment: I found this syntax being used in various "obfuscated" scripts. Whether it be paid JS scripts or some Trojan encryption scripts.